# Is it possible to enforce mathematical constraints between tensorflow neural network output nodes?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, constraints

Is it possible to enforce mathematical constraints between tensorflow neural network output nodes in the last layer?

For example, monotonicity between nodes, such as output node 1 being larger than node 2, which in turn is larger than node 3, and so forth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general -- not really, not directly, at least. Keras layers support arguments for constraints on the *weights*, and you may be able to translate a desired output constraint into a weight constraint instead -- but otherwise, you will need to think about how to set up the structure of your network such that the constraints are fulfilled.

Here is a sketch for how a monotonicity constraint might be possible. Actually including this in a model likely requires creating a custom `Layer` subclass or perhaps using the functional API.

First, let's create some dummy data. This could be the output of a standard `Dense` layer (4 is batch size, 5 the number of outputs).

```
raw_outputs = tf.random.normal([4, 5])
>>> <tf.Tensor: shape=(4, 5), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[ 0.3989258 , -1.7693167 ,  0.13419539,  1.1059834 ,  0.3271042 ],
       [ 0.6493515 , -1.4397207 ,  0.05153034, -0.2730962 , -1.1569825 ],
       [-1.3043666 ,  0.20206456, -0.3841469 ,  1.8338723 ,  1.2728293 ],
       [-0.3725195 ,  1.1708363 , -0.01634515, -0.01382025,  1.2707714 ]],
      dtype=float32)>
```

Next, make all outputs be positive using `softplus`. Think of this as the output activation function. Any function that returns values >= 0 will do. For example, you could use `tf.exp` but the exponential growth might lead to numerical issues. I would not recommend `relu` since the hard 0s prevent gradients from flowing -- usually a bad idea in the output layer.

```
positive_outputs = tf.nn.softplus(raw_outputs)
>>> <tf.Tensor: shape=(4, 5), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[0.9123723 , 0.15738781, 0.7624942 , 1.3918277 , 0.8700147 ],
       [1.0696293 , 0.21268418, 0.71924424, 0.56589293, 0.2734058 ],
       [0.24007489, 0.7992745 , 0.5194075 , 1.9821143 , 1.5197192 ],
       [0.5241344 , 1.4409455 , 0.685008  , 0.68626094, 1.5181118 ]],
      dtype=float32)>
```

Finally, use `cumsum` to add up the values:

```
constrained = tf.cumsum(positive_outputs, reverse=True, axis=-1)

>>> <tf.Tensor: shape=(4, 5), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[4.0940967, 3.1817245, 3.0243368, 2.2618425, 0.8700147],
       [2.8408566, 1.7712271, 1.558543 , 0.8392987, 0.2734058],
       [5.0605907, 4.8205156, 4.021241 , 3.5018334, 1.5197192],
       [4.8544607, 4.3303266, 2.889381 , 2.204373 , 1.5181118]],
      dtype=float32)>
```

As we can see, the outputs for each batch element are monotonically decreasing! This is because each of our original outputs (`positive_outputs`) basically just encodes how much is *added* at each unit, and because we forced them to be positive, the numbers can only get larger (or smaller in this case because of `reverse=True` in `cumsum`).

Answer (score -1):

There are many ways one is neurons learning and the second is mathematics Fn or both by scores weights or rewards or learning from other neurons.

This is one way I teach the networks to lean, you may study from the online sample.

```
X = tf.compat.v1.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=( (10, 88, 80, 4)))
y = tf.compat.v1.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(1, 1))
X_action = tf.compat.v1.get_variable('X_action', dtype = tf.float32, initializer = tf.random.normal((1, 1))) # X_var
in_training_mode = tf.compat.v1.get_variable('in_training_mode', dtype = tf.float32, initializer = tf.random.normal((1, 1))) # X_var

loss = tf.reduce_mean(input_tensor=tf.square((X * y) - (X * X_action))) *
optimizer = tf.compat.v1.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate)
training_op = optimizer.minimize(loss)
```

This is another way me for the similar tasks with simple configuration just select the correct optimizer and loss Fn that performs faster learning, the previous sample is just Error roots mean sequare.

```
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Nadam(
    learning_rate=0.00001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-07,
    name='Nadam'
)
lossfn = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=lossfn, metrics=['accuracy'])current version.
```

Comment: How does this answer the question at all?

Comment: I agree, this answer doesn't seem to be related to my question.